Movie about a guy who searches for a girl he fell in love with
This is an American colored movie, that I saw 2 years ago. I think it was released between 2000 and 2008. Not entirely sure.
The plot is about a guy who falls in love with a girl.
He spends the majority of the movie time looking for her.
But ends up dealing with another girl (a friend of the first girl) who pretends that she is the one whom he loves.
The friend does a lot of trickery to prevent the two people from meeting.
In one scene, the guy asks for coffee, and the (fake) girl couldn't find cups so she pours coffee in wine glasses. It is later revealed that she doesn't know where the (true) girl keeps them.
The movie ends up with the impostor exposed and they finally meet.

Sounds like Wicker Park  (I love that movie)

A young Chicago advertising executive believes a woman he sees in a café is his long-lost love. His belief leads to obsession, as he puts his life on hold in order to trail her




The ending scene



